# Platform independent htonl() function and >> operator on little endian

Tags: cross-platform, bit-shift, endianness, htonl

I’m trying to understand following platform independent htonl() code:

```
uint32_t htonl(uint32_t val)
{
    uint8_t v[4];
    uint32_t *result = (uint32_t *)v;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        v[i] = (uint8_t)(val >> ((3-i) * 8));
    }

    return *result;
}
```

I made up an example and hope someone can confirm my assumptions are correct.

Suppose we have 0x 4A 3B 2C 1D at address 100.
On a BE machine it would look like

Adress: Byte value

> 100: 4A
>
> 101: 3B
>
> 102: 2C
>
> 103: 1D

On an LE machine it would look like

> Adress: Byte value
>
> 100: 1D
>
> 101: 2C
>
> 102: 3B
>
> 103: 4A

Now we call htonl() and store the result from address 500

On BE:

> Adress: Byte value
>
> 500: 4A
>
> 501: 3B
>
> 502: 2C
>
> 503: 1D

On LE:

> Address: Byte value
>
> 500: 4A
>
> 501: 3B
>
> 502: 2C
>
> 503: 1D

So calling htonl() for BE had no net effect and for LE reversed the byte order.

Now for the htonl() code. Let’s take the first iteration (i=0) from the for –loop.

My assumptions are:

For a BE system:

> (uint8_t)(val >> 24) will shift the byte with value 4A from address 100 to >address 103
>
> V[0] is address 500

For an LE system:

> (uint8_t)(val >> 24) will shift the byte with value 4A from address 103 to address 100 (so from a BE perspective this would be a left shift).
>
> V[0] is address 500 – this works because v[8] is uint8_t. If v would be uint64_t then v[0] would be address 503 and htonl() would have no effect  for LE either.

With these assumptions I can understand what’s happening, but are my assumptions correct?

Thanks for reading…